# How to connect to a servlet when both machines are on the same wifi?

Tags: android, servlets, ip-address

Is it possible to connect to a servlet hosted on one machine from another machine when both are sharing the same wifi network. What is the IP address that we can provide for the servlet hosting machine? I need to test a functionality in my android app where i am inserting data into a DB via a servlet. Problem is my server (servlet+db hosting) and the android dev. machine both share the same wifi network.

Comment: Usually it is a local IP, something like: `192.168.1.x`.

Comment: I dont have a static IP for my WiFi network. If I try localhost or 10.0.2.2 then it just tries to connect on the dev. machine itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly doable if you do not have any firewall rules blocking such access on the host machine.

As 'Eng.Found' pointed out, try using the IP address that is assigned to the Server. If 10.0.2.2. tries to connect to the dev machine itself, it certainly is not the IP address of the Server. To detail it further,

First make sure you can access the servlet via localhost on the Server itself. If yes, then get the ip address of the Server and ping it from your dev machine/another device. If you can ping it then you have access to the machine. Else you might have to make sure that some firewall rule(s) is not blocking it.

Ping however cannot be associated with ports so you can use a command like 'netstat' on the Server's console to get a list of all ports its listening to (if desired).

As a quick test for non-static IP address, you can also set the host to 0.0.0.0 to listen to all interfaces on the Server. If it's a linux machine you can simply try 'export HOST=0.0.0.0' on your shell window to set the HOST for the session.
For Windows, you might need to edit the 'hosts' file. In XP, it can be found at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Now try the Server's IP address with the port and servlet url from a different machine on the same wifi network and hopefully you will get a response back.

Also do note, based on the server you are using as the servlet container, there are also settings that might be useful for you to try out.